# How to force render to wait for promise to finish?

Tags: reactjs, promise, pouchdb, react-props

I am trying to pass the db reference through props, but I receive null in the Home component. If I disregard the promise and take off the await, everything works fine, except if the remote db is updated; then it takes two reloads to see the changes for obvious reasons.

I am wondering how to force this promise to go through before the prop is sent to the Home component, or how to update the prop once the promise has gone through.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    db: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setUpDB();
  }

  setUpDB = async () => {
    const remoteDB = PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/db_name');
    const localDB = PouchDB('db_name');
    await remoteDB.replicate.to(localDB);
    this.setState({
      db: localDB,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
            <Home
              db={this.state.db}
            />
          )}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount()` function might end up being called multiple times before the initial `render()` is called so might result in triggering multiple side-effects. Due to this fact it is not recommended to use this function for any side-effect causing operations(AJAX calls). Use `componentDidMount()` instead.
This function will be called after `render()` is finished in each of the re-render cycles. This means that you can be sure that the component and all its sub-components have properly rendered itself. Due to the fact that this is the only function that is guaranteed to be called only once in each re-render cycle it is recommended to use this function for any side-effect causing operations.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.setUpDB();
```

}

Comment: I have always done componentDidMount actually, only ended up using the other while trying to mess around with it lol. That wasn't the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to fix it. Instead of replicating the db in App.js, I did it in index.js and rendered everything following the replication.

BTW, I render the app on error as well so that if the user is offline, it will still use the local db.

```
const startApp = () => {
  // Set Up DB
  const remoteDB = PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/db_name');
  const localDB = PouchDB('db_name');
  remoteDB.replicate.to(localDB)
  .on('complete', () =>
    renderApp(localDB)
  ).on('error', (err) =>
    renderApp(localDB)
  );
};

const renderApp = (db) => {
  // Render App
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <App db={db} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

startApp();
```